# How can I improve the runtime of Python implementation of cycle detection in Course Schedule problem?

Tags: python, python-3.x

My aim is to improve the speed of my Python code that has been successfully accepted in [a leetcode problem, Course Schedule](https://leetcode.com/problems/course-schedule/).

I am aware of the algorithm but even though I am using O(1) data-structures, my runtime is still poor: around 200ms.

My code uses dictionaries and sets:

```
from collections import defaultdict


class Solution:
    def canFinish(self, numCourses: int, prerequisites: List[List[int]]) -> bool:
        course_list = []
        pre_req_mapping = defaultdict(list)
        visited = set()
        stack = set()
        def dfs(course):
            if course in stack:
                return False
            stack.add(course)
            visited.add(course)
            for neighbor in pre_req_mapping.get(course, []):
                if neighbor in visited:
                    no_cycle = dfs(neighbor)
                    if not no_cycle:
                        return False
            stack.remove(course)
            return True
        # for course in range(numCourses):
        #     course_list.append(course)
        for pair in prerequisites:
            pre_req_mapping[pair[1]].append(pair[0])
        for course in range(numCourses):
            if course in visited:
                continue
            no_cycle = dfs(course)
            if not no_cycle:
                return False
        return True
```

What else can I do to improve the speed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling `dfs()` for a given `course` multiple times.
But its return value won't change.
So we have an opportunity to [memoize](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache) it.
Change your algorithmic approach (here, to dynamic programming)
for the big win.
It's a space vs time tradeoff.
EDIT:
Hmmm, you are *already* memoizing most of the computation
with `visited`, so `lru_cache` would mostly improve clarity
rather than runtime.
It's just a familiar idiom for caching a result.

It would be helpful to add a `#` comment citing a reference
for the algorithm you implemented.

This is a very nice expression, with defaulting:
`pre_req_mapping.get(course, [])`
If you use [timeit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html) you may find that the generated bytecode
for an empty tuple `()` is a tiny bit more efficient than that
for an empty list `[]`, as it involves fewer allocations.
Ok, some style nits follow, unrelated to runtime.

As an aside, youAreMixingCamelCase and_snake_case.
PEP-8 asks you to please stick with just snake_case.

This is a fine choice of identifier name:

```
    for pair in prerequisites:
```

But instead of the cryptic `[0]`, `[1]` dereferences,
it would be easier to read a tuple unpack:

```
    for course, prereq in prerequisites:
```

`if not no_cycle:` is clumsy.
Consider inverting the meaning of dfs' return value,
or rephrasing the assignment as:

```
        cycle = not dfs(course)
```

Comment: So, I changed `pre_req_mapping.get(course, [])` to `pre_req_mapping.get(course, ())` and my runtime reduced to 130ms.

Comment: OMG! I changed the `pair[0], pair[1]` stuff to tuple unpacking: `for course, prereq in prerequisites` and my runtime is now 100ms which is better than 79% of the Python submissions. Thank you!

I guess the only other improvement would be to avoid using stacks.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are doing it in good way, but since Python is an interpreted language, it's normal to have slow runtime compared with compiled languages like C/C++ and Java, especially for large inputs.

Try to write the same code in C/C++ for example and compare the speed between them.